# favicon.png vs favicon.ico - why should I use PNG instead of ICO?

Tags: favicon, png, ico

Other than the fact that PNG is a more common image format, is there any technical reason to favor favicon.png vs. favicon.ico?

I'm supporting modern browsers which all support PNG favorite icons.

Answer (score 273, accepted):

Answer replaced (and turned Community Wiki) due to numerous updates and notes from various others in this thread:

- ICOs and PNGs both allow full alpha channel based transparency
- ICO allows for backwards compatibility to older browsers (e.g. IE6)
- PNG probably has broader tooling support for transparency, but you can find tools to create alpha-channel ICOs as well, such as the [Dynamic Drive tool](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) and [Photoshop plugin](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/#icoformat) mentioned by @mercator.

Feel free to consult the other answers here for more details.

Comment: ICO also allows alpha channel

Comment: -1 ICO supports multiple resolutions including full alpha channel. By the way, 1-bit alpha is known as "transparency". The only real limit ICO has had was with icons larger or equal to 256 in length (any direction), though it's been overcome several times.

Comment: -1 .ico also allow multiple resolution in one file (16x16 and 32x32 for example). So the icone stay nice when you create a shortcut on a desktop.

Comment: Most browsers favor the favicon.ico in the root over the linked one. With your solution most browsers would pick the *non-transparent* .ico instead of the linked png.

Comment: @lode why would it particularly pick a non-transparent ico instead of a transparent ico?

Comment: Can't help but notice that this accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score 410):

All modern browsers (tested with Chrome 4, Firefox 3.5, IE8, Opera 10 and Safari 4) will always request a `favicon.ico` unless you've specified a shortcut icon via `<link>`. So if you don't explicitly specify one, it's best to always have a `favicon.ico` file, to avoid a 404. [Yahoo! suggests you make it small and cacheable.](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#favicon)

And you don't have to go for a PNG just for the alpha transparency either. [ICO files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) support alpha transparency just fine (i.e. 32-bit color), though hardly any tools allow you to create them. I regularly use [Dynamic Drive's FavIcon Generator](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/) to create `favicon.ico` files with alpha transparency. It's the only online tool I know of that can do it.

There's also a free [Photoshop plug-in](http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/#icoformat) that can create them.

Comment: Great hint this Dynamic Drive tool! Instantly bookmarked. Thanks!

Comment: Adding my thanks for the Dynamic Drive FavIcon. Very very cool!

Comment: re tools, it is largely untrue; there are several icon designing tools. I wrote a simple one myself in the past.

Comment: @Christian, I know there are plenty dedicated icon tools that can do it; there's nothing really special about 32-bit color. But the only thing I ever really need an `.ico` for is for a favicon, so I tend to rely on free, online tools... I've also used this Photoshop plug-in, though: http://www.telegraphics.com.au/sw/#icoformat. I think I stopped using that for some reason, but I can't remember why. It works fine too.

Comment: Don't use photoshop for small icons...don't ask why, just don't. It dirties icon's format reputation. :)

Comment: For those that don't have $650 bucks for Photoshop, you can use pixlr.com (for free) to create, edit and save .png files with full layering and transparency :)

Comment: @Pacerier It's incredibly difficult to get `.ico` editing in PS. And even if you do, the end result is soo bad, you'd think `.bmp` was a better format (it adds a lot of meta-data making re-editing a huge pain).

Comment: The Dynamic Drive favicon generator doesn't seem to be all that great. I tried creating a favicon from a png file and it made the whole image more transparent than it was before; furthermore, if the extra size options are marked, the 48x48 layer has a white border between opaque and transparent regions. Maybe they changed the code somehow?

Comment: @Waldir Is your PNG image by any chance an 8-bit PNG with alpha transparency? If you're on Linux you can use the `file` command to find out (among other things, it'll say `8-bit/color RGBA` for 32-bit or `8-bit colormap` for 8-bit). Or try using e.g. [pngcrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush) (`pngcrush -c 6 input.png output.png`) to force it to 32-bit to see if Dynamic Drive can handle it then.

Comment: @mercator it was 32-bit. For reference, here's the [original](http://i.imgur.com/WZNRkcY.png) and Dynamic Drive's [48px icon](http://i.imgur.com/IDjksJE.png). Both were put in a with a black background to make the transparency change and white "border" more visible.

Comment: Another tool that I mostly use to create favicons is [FavIcon (htmlkit)](http://favicon.htmlkit.com/favicon/). From the readme: "package has 2 image formats in a single file: 16*16-pixel 256-color and 32*32-pixel 256-color." - I made a test the generator from the answer above gave me a file of 2KB, the tool I mentioned gave me a 6KB file.

Comment: Call me crazy, but I've made favicons by creating .png (full transparency) and just renaming the extension. No problems so far. Thoughts?

Comment: @mikevoermans: It's still read as a PNG; most modern browsers don't care so much about file extensions. BTW, this is the best answer and should be the accepted one.

Comment: I use icoconverter, which supports 32-bit (transparent) ico files. Note that it checks 48x48 by default, but that's probably unnecessary. 32x32 is fine. http://www.icoconverter.com/

Comment: @mikevoermans You are crazy. But the people that allow it to work are crazier.

Comment: https://realfavicongenerator.net/ tool looks promising too. I have just used it once though.

Comment: This is a great tool, I use to generate my favicons in https:://favicon.cc but this one you suggested is better, thanks!

Answer (score 65):

.png files are nice, but .ico files provide alpha-channel transparency, too, **plus** they give you backwards compatibility.

Have a look at which type StackOverflow uses for example (note that it's transparent):

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/favicon.ico"> 
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

The apple-itouch thingy is for iphone users that make a shortcut to a website.

Comment: PNG can also provide alpha channel

Comment: yeah, my point was that ico's can do everything that png's can do (alpha-transparency) as a favicon, and additionally they are supported by all browsers since year 0.

Comment: according to wikipedia internet explorer will fail to support a line like this: <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://example.com/image.ico" />

Comment: Chances are the website doesn't support browsers since year 0 so why bother? Try and load a modern website in IE6 and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 29):

The theoretical advantage of *.ico files is that they are containers than can hold more than one icon. You could for instance store an image with alpha channel and a 16 colour version for legacy systems, or you could add 32x32 and 48x48 icons (which would show up when e.g. dragging a link to Windows explorer).

This good idea, however, tends to clash with browser implementations.

Comment: Related to this is the fact that IE9 also uses those large icons to pin to the win7 taskbar see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723715/where-does-ie9-look-for-the-large-favicons

Comment: Uhm, theoretical? The same icon shipped with Windows 7 can be used in Windows 95 in 8bit color mode. I think that's quite practical, no?

Comment: Please note that this answer was written on 2009. The browser scene at the time was vastly different than it's now.

Answer (score 17):

PNG has 2 advantages: it has smaller size and it's more widely used and supported (except in case favicons).
As mentioned before ICO, can have multiple size icons, which is useful for desktop applications, but not too much for websites.
I would recommend you to put a favicon.ico in the root of your application. An if you have access to the Head of your website pages use the  tag to point to a png file.
So older browser will show the favicon.ico and newer ones the png.

To create Png and Icon files I would recommend [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/).

Comment: Not so much for websites? Wait till everyone starts using retina-like displays; suddenly there will be a very good reason why one might to include a 32x32 or larger size in their favicon...

Comment: We are talking about favicons so the issue of support is in fact the opposite of what you say

Comment: +1 Addresses the original question and doesn't get bogged down in transparency.  Also mentions an app which *does* support .ico format.

Answer (score 13):

Some social tools like Google+ use a simple method to get a favicon for external links, fetching
http://your.domainname.com/favicon.ico

Since they don't prefetch the HTML content, the `<link>` tag will not work. In this case, you might want to use a mod_rewrite rule or just place the file in the default location.

Comment: Don't know whether it is true or false but it was the deciding argument for me to go and create favicon.ico in root in addition to png i have.

Comment: I know this from work at http://telly.com, -via paul lindner who is on the google plus team. https://plus.google.com/117259934788907243749/about

Comment: Placing the favicon in the root is the *de facto* standard, so I would adhere to it for reasons such as mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 10):

An ico can **be** a png.

More precisely, you can store one or more png inside this minimal container format, instead of the usual bitmap+alpha that everyone strongly associates with ico.

Support is old, [appearing in Windows Vista](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473) (2007) and is well supported by browsers, though not necessarily by icon editing software.

Any valid png (whole including header) can be prepended by a [6 byte ico header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#Outline) and 16 byte image directory.
GIMP has native support. Simply export as ico and tick "Compressed (PNG)".

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, I do this:

```html
    <!-- Favicon - Generic -->
    <link rel="icon" href="path/favicon-32_x_32.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" href="path/favicon-57_x_57.png" sizes="57x57">
    <link rel="icon" href="path/favicon-76_x_76.png" sizes="76x76">
    <link rel="icon" href="path/favicon-96_x_96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" href="path/favicon-128_x_128.png" sizes="128x128">
    <link rel="icon" href="path/favicon-192_x_192.png" sizes="192x192">
    <link rel="icon" href="path/favicon-228_x_228.png" sizes="228x228">
    <!-- Favicon - Android -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="path/favicon-196_x_196.png" sizes="196x196">
    <!-- Favicon - iOS -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="path/favicon-120_x_120.png" sizes="120x120">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="path/favicon-152_x_152.png" sizes="152x152">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="path/favicon-180_x_180.png" sizes="180x180">
```

And I *still* keep the favicon.ico in root.

Comment: Also I use derivv.com to get all sizes from the oversized square favicon.png. Set all sizes once, then export CSV and have it  somewhere for quick access.

Answer (score 5):

Avoid PNG in any case if you want reliable IE6 compatibility.

Comment: There's no reason why you can't use both - an ico in the directory tree for IE6 and a PNG specified via a `<link>` in the page code for modern browsers.

Comment: Why would you use both? If you're going to bother making an ico what benefit would using a png as well have? Surely it's just extra work and extra code.

Comment: @Mr_Chimp because png is an open standard and more forward-looking? It's one extra line of markup.

Comment: Hi @Orcra - I think you would not find it so funny had you been reading this ~8 years ago when I wrote this answer, and had to consider things like IE6 :) StackOverflow allows editing answers so please feel free to update it yourself to something relevant today

Comment: @aehike you have a fair point, my bad for not checking the timestamp.

Comment: @aehike, might I suggest you delete this answer?  It is not really relevant today - and, you can earn the 'Disciplined' badge from SO! :)

Comment: hi @CFPSupport - thanks for the suggestion. I don't actively maintain my old StackOverflow answers. I believe SO has features to let you flag an answer for deletion.

Comment: @aehlke - yes, I could flag it, but that is for a 'serious problems' sort of thing - that would give a negative strike, I think.....  Well, anyway, you have a good rep and I'm just getting started.... - was looking through how to get more badges and then I ran across this post.  I won't flag it (but I'd take that badge if I could! :)  Someday I'll have enough good answers to afford deleting one!  See you around SO.....

Comment: @CFPSupport apologies for the pushback - I could manage this specific answer, but I categorically feel no ongoing responsibility for actively managing and grooming all the content I posted here nearly a decade ago so I'm hoping for a better systemic solution