# I need to reduce size of image? Can somebody assist me?

Tags: image, .ico

I have a 512x512 1.03 mb .ico picture and need to upload it to a website that only accepts pictures 1mb large(or smaller idk) Can somebody help me and tell me a way to reduce the size of the image.

Comment: This is a duplicate question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277861/favicon-ico-filesize-60kb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277861/favicon-ico-filesize-60kb)

Answer (score 2):

You can either compress/reduce the filesize of the icon (I recommend using ImageMagick to do this, you can download it [here](http://imagemagick.org)), or you can make the dimensions smaller. However, if you are putting an ico file on a website I recommend using a different image format, such as .png. You can convert it to png using a website called [ConvertICO](http://www.convertico.com/).

I hope this helps,

Santiago

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [this page](http://zoompf.com/blog/2012/04/instagram-and-optimizing-favicons) specially compression of ICO files and 4-bit option.