# Necessary to add link tag for favicon.ico?

Tags: html, favicon

Are there any modern browsers that won't detect the favicon.ico automatically? Is there any reason to add the link tag for favicon.ico?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

My guess is that it's only necessary to include it in the HTML document if you decide to go with GIF or PNG...

Comment: I've never seen that any browser had needed it. Do you have any examples?

Comment: I can name some browsers that have preference settings whether or not to go look for `favicon.ico` automatically. So if you want to be sure that your icon shows up, better include a link in your HTML. By the way, .png files are usually smaller than comparable .ico files.

Comment: Please name some Mr Lister :) No shark555, I can't name any...

Comment: Firefox (and other Gecko based browsers like SeaMonkey) has several settings to fine-tune its behaviour. `browser.chrome.favicons` set to true will look for favicon.ico in the root; if false, it will only load an icons if specified in the HTML page. See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.chrome.favicons and related pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you have to include <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644684/do-you-have-to-include-link-rel-icon-href-favicon-ico-type-image-x-icon)

Answer (score 278, accepted):

**To choose a *different location or file type (e.g. [PNG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-png) or [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=link-icon-svg))* for the favicon:**
One reason can be that you want to have the icon in a specific location, perhaps in the images folder or something alike. For example:

```
<link rel="icon" href="_/img/favicon.png">
```

This diferent location may even be a CDN, just like SO seems to do with `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">`.

To learn more about using other file types like PNG check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1344122/419956).

**For *cache busting* purposes:**
Add a query string to the path for cache-busting purposes:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=1.1">
```

Favicons are very heavily cached and this a great way to ensure a refresh.

---

**Footnote about default location:**
As far as the first bit of the question: all modern browsers would detect a favicon at the default location, so that's *not* a reason to use a `link` for it.

---

**Footnote about `rel="icon"`:**
As indicated by [@Semanino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31132296/419956), using `rel="shortcut icon"` is an old technique which was required by older versions of Internet Explorer, but in most cases can be replaced by the more correct `rel="icon"` instruction. [The article @Semanino based this on](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon) properly links to [the appropriate spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#linkTypes) which shows a `rel` value of `shortcut` isn't a valid option.

Comment: Should this go in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes. (See "Permitted parent elements" [in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) or "Contexts" in [the W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-link-element)).

Comment: It's 2016 - and Chrome still (or again?) is not recognizing the default favicon.ico in the root if you specifiy also other icons...

Answer (score 57):

**Please note** that both the HTML5 specification of W3C and WhatWG **standardize**

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

Note the value of the "rel" attribute!

The value `shortcut icon` for the `rel` attribute is a very old Internet Explorer specific extension and ***deprecated***.

So please consider not using it any more and updating your files so they are standards compliant and are displayed correctly in all browsers.

You might also want to take a look at this great post: [rel="shortcut icon" considered harmful](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon)

Comment: Not quite "deprecated" (it was never actually part of any spec). However, the [HTML5 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-icon) states, "For historical reasons, the icon keyword may be preceded by the keyword "shortcut". If the "shortcut" keyword is present, it must be come immediately before the icon keyword and the two keywords must be separated by only a single U+0020 SPACE character." Also note that, "There is no default type for resources given by the icon keyword."

Answer (score 13):

> ```
> <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/favicon.png" />
> <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="http://example.com/favicon.gif" />
> <link rel="icon" type="image/jpeg" href="http://example.com/favicon.jpeg" />
> <link rel="icon" type="image/webp" href="http://example.com/favicon.webp" />
> ```

**It all depends on which format of image you like to use!**
***if you have an icon of your website, it will be much better for UX!***

### demo

> show logo in the browser tab

[image]

Comment: http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/examples/favicons/  links:

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon#comments links:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#rel-icon links:

Comment: UX has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @paddotk what I mean is that the user can easily tell which tab belongs to the target website when open multi-tabs in the browser if there is a favicon icon shows in the tab.

Answer (score 4):

##### Update Oct 2020:

So if you are on this page scratching your head why my favicon is not working , then read along. I tried all the things (which I supposedly thought I was doing right) yet favicon was not showing up on browser tabs.

Here is **one line simple** cracker code that worked flawlessly:

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://abcde.neocities.org/bla123.jpg" size="16x16" type="image/jpg">
```

[image]

Notes:

1. Put the image in the **ROOT** folder ( In one of my unsuccessful attempts , I was not using root dir)
2. Use direct favicon **url link** ( instead of href="images/bla123.jpg").
3. I placed this tag just **below the <**title**> tag** in the <**Header**>
4. I made the favicon size **64x64 px** and size was 2.16 KB

I tested it on Firefox, Chrome, Edge, and opera.
OS: Win 10, Mac OSX, ios and Android .Also I did not experience any cashing issues, worked pretty much as soon as I refreshed the page.

Comment: Confirming that favicon size indeed makes a difference

Answer (score 2):

We can add for all devices with platform specific size

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="fav_icons/apple-icon-180x180.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="fav_icons/android-icon-192x192.pn">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="fav_icons/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="fav_icons/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="fav_icons/favicon-16x16.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

The bottom line is not all browsers *will* actually look for your *favicon.ico* file. Some browsers allow users to choose whether or not it should automatically look. Therefore, in order to ensure that it will *always* appear and get looked at, you do have to define it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment animuson. Can you name some browsers that wont look automaticly?

Comment: @user1087110: I don't know any off the top of my head, and honestly who cares. The point is you can't assume it will and you need to account for those that won't.

Comment: Since it is not relevant anymore, you can delete your answer to clean up the page.