# is using apple-touch-icon as favicon possible?

Tags: html, favicon

I have noticed that HTML5 Boilerplate and dev websites like css-tricks.com use only apple-touch-icon as any reference to favicon, and that image is indeed displayed in a browser. I was not following this topic for a while and am confused to how this works. Is it safe to now only include a touch-icon and will it be displayed in various browsers?

Comment: uhm. You can use whatever image you like but you need to use both meta tags. The one for apples touch icons and the one for favicons

Comment: @Sumit that's how I'd do it normally, but I noticed that various web sites, like one mentioned in my question only use apple-touch-icon, and HTML5 Boilerplate does that as well, hence I'm confused to why they all do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A favicon.ico file is used by the browser automatically if it's in the root directly of your page/app.

If you want to add a favicon in a different format (e.g. `png`), of you want to add it from another source (e.g. a subdirectory like `/img`) or if you want to make the browser load a new version of the file (e.g. `favicon.ico?v=2`) you use the link tag.

More info here:
[Necessary to add link tag for favicon.ico?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218178/necessary-to-add-link-tag-for-favicon-ico)