# Favicon in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, favicon

I wanted to add a favicon to my WebApp

I'm using this line, but it doesn't work:

```
HTML("<link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"image.png\" />")
```

inside the ui.R script and outside the `shinyUI()` function. Also I have the image.png where the server.R and ui.R are. (I've also tried putting it inside the folder /www )

Do you know how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> If you're using a local runapp, then putting one in
>   /www/favicon.ico should work, I believe.
>
> You could also insert this somewhere in your UI:
>
> tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", href="URL-to-favicon"))

[Joe Cheng](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/Vz3DihUOrfc)

Comment: Thank you, Joe. It was really easy. Shiny automatically detects there is a favicon in /www/favicon.ico

Comment: tags$head solution stopped working for me after enabling HTTPS for the site, most likely because the tags$head href was http. Putting favicon at /srv/shiny-server/favicon.ico worked for me, though.

Comment: When I deploy it on shinyapps.io then it does not show the logo. Only works in the local.

Comment: I got it working—with a local run—using `tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", href="favicon.ico"))`, with the image file in the 'www' directory.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert your favicon into base64 text (check favicon.cc website, they already do it) and write:

```
ui <- function(){tagList(

fluidPage(


titlePanel(
  windowTitle = "Title that appears in the browser bar",
  title = tags$head(tags$link(rel="icon", 
                              href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEAetc", 
                              type="image/x-icon")
                    )),

sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel(
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible problem the OP is having is that the favicon filename should be favicon.ico and not image.png.

Some additional details here: [favicon.png vs favicon.ico - why should I use PNG instead of ICO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344122/favicon-png-vs-favicon-ico-why-should-i-use-png-instead-of-ico)

The important part being:

> All modern browsers (tested with Chrome 4, Firefox 3.5, IE8, Opera 10
>   and Safari 4) will always request a favicon.ico unless you've
>   specified a shortcut icon via . So if you don't explicitly
>   specify one, it's best to always have a favicon.ico file, to avoid a
>   404.

Comment: Your quote contradicts your answer. The OP has specified a shortcut via a link tag.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get favicon to work in r shiny using this code on both internet explorer and chrome:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    windowTitle = "NOAA",
    title = tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", 
                                href="https://www.noaa.gov/sites/all/themes/custom/noaa/favicon.ico", 
                                type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon")))
###... rest of code
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
###... rest of code
}

runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```