# Display Icon in the title bar of Shiny app page

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for some way to display some Snap in the title bar just before the Name of my `Shiny App ('My App')` as below:

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(       
        fluidPage(title = "My App", 
            selectInput(inputId = "Pick", label = "Chose", choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, size = NULL, width = 300))
        )

server = function(input, output, session) {
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have tried with having `HTML` tag in the title argument as below, however it is not displaying anything.

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(       
        fluidPage(title = div(img(src = 'https://guidetoiceland.is/image/389003/x/0/the-beautiful-waterfalls-of-south-iceland-seljalandsfoss-skogafoss-amp-gljufrabui-1.jpg', "My App")), 
            selectInput(inputId = "Pick", label = "Chose", choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'), selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, size = NULL, width = 300))
        )

server = function(input, output, session) {
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would appreciate if someone guide me towards the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello I think you are going to find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096187/favicon-in-shiny. Possible duplicate of previously answered question

Comment: Hi  Billy34, I am able to follow your link. Now I could display icon in Title. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel(
    title =
      tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/gif", href = "https://guidetoiceland.is/image/389003/x/0/the-beautiful-waterfalls-of-south-iceland-seljalandsfoss-skogafoss-amp-gljufrabui-1.jpg"),
    "My App"
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "Pick",
    label = "Chose",
    choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = FALSE,
    selectize = TRUE,
    size = NULL,
    width = 300
  ))
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Unless I misunderstood your question here is the output. You have to open it in a browser to see it:
[image]

Comment: Hi Lee, your solution doesnt display any icon. But anyway I followed the link  stackoverflow.com/questions/30096187/favicon-in-shiny

Comment: @Bogaso code works fine for me. Not sure why it is not working for you

Comment: @Bogaso, I realize my code only works in Firefox. I had not tested it in IE or Edge

Comment: Hi Lee, yes I agree. That not working with Chrome too, however IE is fine.