# Display the icon of my app in the browser's bar with shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, browser, module, dashboard

I'm trying to add the icon of my app in the browser bar (like all the known icons the pic).

[image]

My app consists of modules, so that the code of the main ui looks as follow:

```
    ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = ...),
          dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
          dashboardBody(
            tabBox(
                tabPanel(title = "first tab",
                         myModuleIO("first tab")),
                tabPanel(title = "second tab",
                         myModuleIO("second tab"))
            )
          )
     )
```

I tried already the solutions in [Display Icon in the title bar of Shiny app page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498574/display-icon-in-the-title-bar-of-shiny-app-page) but it showed the code instead of the image;

I tried to add the line

```
title = div(img(src = "myapp.png"), "My app name")
```

once in the dashboardPage directly

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
     title = div(img(src = "myapp.png"), "My app name"))
```

that showed the text "div(..)" instead of the pic; also I tried to put it inside the tabPanel or in the fluidPage underneath my module (inside the tabPanel) again only the code is shown ... could anyone help please?

thanks

**Edit**
the tags$link in the link above also didn't work that's why I said I tried it!

Comment: The existing question you pointed to used `tags$link(rel = "icon", type = "image/gif", href ="...")` to get that to work. You don't seem to be using `tags$link` at all. The icon is set via a `<link>` tag, not the page title.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did try the tags$link but that didn't work either.

Comment: Please show the code where you attempted to use `tags$link` so we can find any possible problems. Again, the icon has nothing to do with the page title. It's a separate property usually called the "favicon"