# How do I add a favicon to Knitr html browser tab output in R?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a knitr program that renders to html in a browser page.
Id like to put a favicon .png image in the browser tab that the output opens up to.

I have seen answers for this with shiny, but not standalone knitr

[Favicon in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096187/favicon-in-shiny)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to get a favicon, you have to insert the following `HTML` element in the `<head>` element of the rendered document:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="link_to_your_favicon.png">
```

There are many methods to achieve this goal.
I recommend to use the `includes` option.

For instance, save the following line in a file named `favicon.html`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.r-project.org/favicon-32x32.png">
```

If you render the following `Rmd` document, you will get a `HTML` file with the R project's favicon:

```
---
title: "Favicon"
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: "favicon.html" 
---

A document with a favicon
```

Comment: this is how to use a local image instead of a url: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74521272/4169588