# Adding logo to browser title in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to add a logo in the browser.

```
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(title = "test me",
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(),
                    dashboardBody())

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you run the above code you and open the app in your browser you will see the test me show up in the title of the browser. I would like to add a logo to the title as well. Right now you will see a "globe" but instead i would like to see my company logo next to test me. I see a solution that works in shiny but the same does not work for shinydashboard page. Thanks for your help.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187213/my-favicon-will-not-display-on-a-browser-tab-for-my-app-when-using-open-source-s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My favicon will not display on a browser tab for my app when using open source shiny server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55187213/my-favicon-will-not-display-on-a-browser-tab-for-my-app-when-using-open-source-s)