# how to add favicon to one-page shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I am trying to add a favicon to my shiny app when it is opened in a browser, but I couldn't find a way to do that on a one-page shiny.

Here is an example of my code:

```
ui <- navbarPage(title = "title",
                 selected = "home",
                 theme = shinytheme("readable"),
                 fluid = TRUE,
                 home)



server <- function(input, output) {}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I add a favicon when my app is written like this? All of the solutions I saw are for apps with multiple files, ui.R and server.R.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096187/favicon-in-shiny/30096376

Comment: I specifically said on a one-page shiny app. The one you are suggesting is two script apps.