# How to set favicon.ico properly on vue.js webpack project?

Tags: html, vue.js, webpack, favicon

I have created a `vue webpack` project using `vue-cli`.

```
vue init webpack myproject
```

And then ran the project under `dev` mode:

```
npm run dev
```

I got this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico

So inside webpack, how to import the `favicon.ico` correctly?

Comment: Have you tried just dropping it into the root of the site? :) Or in the public build folder?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Check out the Project Structure of webpack template: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/structure.html

Note that there is a static folder, along with `node_modules`, `src`, etc.

If you put some image into the `static` folder, like `favicon.png`, it will be made available at http://localhost:8080/static/favicon.png

Here is the documentation for static assets: https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

For your favicon issue, you can put a `favicon.ico` or `favicon.png` into the `static` folder and refer in the `<head>` of your index.html as follows:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/favicon.png"/>
    <title>My Vue.js app</title>
    ...
</head>
```

If you do not define a `favicon.ico` in your `index.html`, then the browser will request for a favicon from the website root (default behaviour). If you specify a favicon as above, you will not see that 404 anymore. The favicon will also start showing up in your browser tabs.

As a side note, here is the reason why I prefer PNG instead of ICO file:

[favicon.png vs favicon.ico - why should I use PNG instead of ICO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344122/favicon-png-vs-favicon-ico-why-should-i-use-png-instead-of-ico)

Comment: what if I want to keep my favicon in src/assets? is it best to leave it in static folder along with .gitkeep?

Comment: @AkinHwan I haven't attempted this yet, but if you keep any image in src/assets, it will be treated as a module dependency and will go into the final build file as an inline image (base64 format). This will unnecessarily increase the build size. Nothing to worry, it will not affect the performance in any way.  It is my preference to keep images as "real static assets" as  explained in [the docs](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html). Your preferences may vary. You need to try both methods and choose the one that works for you.

Comment: This answer seems a bit out of date. In the current vue webpack template, there's a **public** directory, not a **static** directory.

Comment: @JakeParis also, using "shortcut" in the link rel is only used for internet explorer.

Comment: This is working for routing but for direct link it is not worked

Answer (score 23):

For some reason, the above solutions did not work for me before converting the default `favicon.ico` file to `favicon.png` and renaming it to `favicon-xyz.png` e.g.  (I have put this file in `/public` folder) and edited the `index.html` file as follows:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon-xyz.png">
    .
    .
    .
</head>
```

Might be useful for someone.

Comment: It works for me nicely. Just needed to put my custom "favicon" icon into the "/public" folder after removing original one.

Comment: This works oddly well

Answer (score 14):

Little update for Laravel 5/6/7/8/9, place your `favicon.ico` or `favicon.png` into the `/public` folder and refer to it in your `index.html` like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
    <title>My Vue.js app</title>
    ...
</head>
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 7):

As of 2022, @Mani answer is a little outdated as [static assets are now served in `public` folder other than `static`.](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)

Just generate a `.ico` favicon file ([this site](https://realfavicongenerator.net/) provides free online favicon generation), rename it to `favicon.ico` and place it in `public` folder, no need to change `index.html`, reload and new favicon will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `shortcut` in `rel` tag like that :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [vue-pwa-asset-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pwa-asset-generator) in order to generate a full set of favicons foreach platform.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This did the trick as per eightballs comments. I needed to move the file to the /public folder and rename it :D

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>gear.png">
    <title>Prodigy</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32504707)