# How to add new css file from node module

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, vue.js

I was trying to enhance vue.js [boilerplate code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0), I wanted to use [flexboxgrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/) with this. I added it in package.json and installed it. I was trying to include this in `index.html` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/./node_modules/flexboxgrid/dist/flexboxgrid.min.css" type="text/css" >
```

But I am getting following error in the browser:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8080/node_modules/flexboxgrid/dist/flexboxgrid.min.css".
```

I am not sure what I should be right way to do this this, what am I doing wring, Please help.

Comment: As the error indicates, the server is serving the file with the wrong headers/mine type. You have to set the correct values I suppose

Comment: @adeneo I have already given `type="text/css"` there, where does this has to be mentioned.

Comment: Is your node_modules folder actually exposed through HTTP? It probably is not (and that is a good thing, by the way). You're getting a MIME type text/html because the web server presumably is responding with an HTML page, after redirecting the non-existing node_modules path to "/".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @1sloc in comments, you are probably getting a 404 error page in HTML.

Till you find a better solution, you may do as follows: copy `flexboxgrid.min.css` to the `static` folder at the project root, and serve it as a static file from there. This is similar to how you would serve a `favicon.ico` for your app.

For details on handling static files, you may refer to the answer in this question:
[How to set favicon.ico properly on vue.js webpack project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190524/how-to-set-favicon-ico-properly-on-vue-js-webpack-project)

Comment: BTW, one solution is to `import "flexboxgrid/dist/flexboxgrid.css"` in your `main.js`, as discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/171). While it may work, I am not a fan of that solution, as I would prefer to see the CSS getting loaded in the header of html.