# Favicon in Vuejs not avaiable on http://localhost:8080/static/favicon.png

Tags: javascript, vue.js, favicon

Well, I tried do like [Manu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/654825/mani) said on [How to set favicon.ico properly on vue.js webpack project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190524/how-to-set-favicon-ico-properly-on-vue-js-webpack-project/40191627)

But my favicon is not avaiable on http://localhost:8080/static/favicon.png

I'm using the Vuejs in history mode. I don't know if that can be it!

1. What I have to do to use a favicon now?
2. The favicon is visible only after built?

Comment: I'm using VueJS in history mode too and I use any favicon the same way and it's working fine. Could you show some code? Have you tried to empty your cache? Or reload your project (close terminal and `npm run dev`)? Tried in another browser too?