# Change favicon Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli-3

How to change favicon on Vuejs CLI ?

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/src/assets/img/logo.png"/>
```

Comment: the favicon.ico is stored in the public folder

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190524/how-to-set-favicon-ico-properly-on-vue-js-webpack-project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set favicon.ico properly on vue.js webpack project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190524/how-to-set-favicon-ico-properly-on-vue-js-webpack-project)

Answer (score 13):

Vue CLI (`3.0.5`) generates projects with the [`<root>/public`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) directory containing the `favicon.ico` and `index.html` (which references the `favicon.ico`).

It seems you have your icon in `<root>/src/assets`. I recommend moving it to `<root>/public`, replacing `favicon.ico` with `jinane-logo-JC.png`, and updating `index.html` accordingly:

```html
<!-- <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico"> --> <!-- REPLACE THIS -->
<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>jinane-logo-JC.png">
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(function() {
    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are using vue cli2, put your fovicon in static files and change 
`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="static/jinane-logo-JC.png"/>` or you are using vue cli3, put your favicon image in public file and change it in index.html in public 
`<link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>jinane-logo-JC.png">`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps : -

1. Copy your desired favicon in public folder in Vue project.
2. Go to your project and look for index.html
3. Find link tag for icon & replace name of "youlogohere" to your logo name

   `< link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>yourlogohere.png">`
4. Run Project and Icon changed.

Answer (score 0):

You shold use [vue-head](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-head) package

Add this code in your `App.vue` file:

```
  export default {
    head: {
       link: [
             {
                 rel: "icon",
                 href: require("./assets/logo.png")
             },
          ]
       }
   }
```

goodluck!