# Why is the link to favicon element commented out on build?

Tags: html, vue.js, favicon

I have been trying to use my own favicon on my vue.js project for some time. I replaced the original vue favicon with my own and it would not work.

I have tried everything every troubleshooting step I can find. Cache cleared, waited a few days, a query to override cache etc

I think I have now narrowed down the problem but cannot understand why it occurs. When I inspect the built web-app in the browser the link element which references the favicon shows the following:

`<!--[if IE]><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><![endif]-->`

The element is commented out and seems to have an if statement attached to it. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a fallback when you are visiting the website in *Internet Explorer* below version *11*

*Internet Explorer <11* doesn't support `.png` images to be used as favicons, but only `.ico` files. Support for `.png` and `.gif` files only became supported from version 11 and onwards.

[image]

So thats why it has the `if` statement around it, the corresponding element will only be parsed when the browser is *IE <11*

Note that the `<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->` is only recognized by *Internet Explorer 10* and versions below *IE 10*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thank you, well that avenue is exhausted now. I still cannot get the favicon to show on any browser.

Comment: Thats a sepperate issue tho ;) you could try this out https://www.favicon-generator.org/ it will generate all necessary files for you.

Comment: Do you have documentation where to position all those files in a vue app? I have used that service but only imported the .ico file

Comment: Maybe you find you answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190524/how-to-set-favicon-ico-properly-on-vue-js-webpack-project

Comment: I have read nearly every stackoverflow question about favicons, still no luck

Comment: Create a new question for that.

Comment: I did and it instantly received two downvotes with no attempt to answer so I removed it