# Favicon not showing up in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, favicon

I'm coding using Vue JS technology and I'm trying to load the favicon but it won't show up. I tried to look for other documentation about it but can't find one. I'm a beginner in this technology hope someone help. Thanks!

Here is my code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

<noscript>
  <strong>
   We're sorry but codesandbox doesn't work properly without 
   JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.
 </strong>
</noscript>
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
```

[Please check the attached image there is the code as well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEPvc.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I have it edited now.

Comment: Hey @Jake, here's another helpful answer,, see this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40191627/11563561,
Go for a static folder

Comment: anything for a fellow developer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vuejs, your favicon.ico should be in either public or assets folder.

---

To access images from assets folder in vue one would do :src="require('@/assets/images/favicon.ico')"

---

To access images from public folder in vue one would do :src="./static/images/favicon.ico"

---

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Welcome @Jake Angelo Vargas!! An upvote would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried to up vote your answer bro. but stack won't let me not until I get 15 Reputation. I only have 7 as of the moment.