# ExpressJs is console logging two times

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I don't understand why is my code logging messages two times when I'm just creating only one server and loading it once in the browser.

**INPUT -**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Hello middleware')
    next(); // Allows the request to continue to the next middleware in line
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Hello middleware v2')
    res.send('<h1>Hello Express!</h1>');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**OUTPUT -**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Hello middleware
Hello middleware v2
Hello middleware
Hello middleware v2
```

**package.json -**

```
{
  "name": "nodeproject1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "node tutorial",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "Arkapratim Sarkar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke the request ? Add some more debug information to the `console.log`, like source port & ip. So you can see if they are multiple requests or there is another problem

Comment: as i mentioned by 'app.listen(3000);' and going to 'localhost:3000'. anyway @eol pointed out that a default icon file is also making a request thus the double logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you perform the request through your browser not only will a request be sent for the corresponding request-path (e.g.`/`) but also for `/favicon.ico` (details are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1344379/3761628)).
Since two requests are made, you see each of your middleware's log message twice.

Comment: thanks for explaining  this. I've been seeing this '/favicon.ico' in network tab of dev tools but didn't think that it is also making a different request.